# How can i let collision objects stop from going through cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to put a rope around the cloth using keyframes but the cloth is not moving backwards. Instead, the rope is moving through the cloth. How can i make sure the cloth simulates tight to the back of the rope.

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I would make the rope a cloth as well, but very very stiff. Then pin it's inner vertices to the outer vertices of the t-shirt.

Comment: Increase the cloth collision quality and see if that works. Also, does that rope have collision enabled? Sometimes a simple mistake is a cause.

Comment: can you elaborate more on "put a rope around the cloth using keyframes" and how you set the collision with the cloth object? maybe upload the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit the question and paste the provided link